# Install R in Linux Server

Tags: r

I have tried install R in Linux operated server system and I dont have admin rights so I couldnt usu "sudo". 
I have download latest version of R from https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz.

Then I started to install and write

./configure

make

After make command I get error "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop."

I couldnt solve this problem.

Comment: There is an apt repository for `r`. I can't recall what it is, but it's in the documents under Debian.  Also, you have a *.tgz which needs to be extracted first. Then cd into the directory.

Comment: If there's *"no makefile found"* then it suggests that the `./configure` did not complete successfully - check its output to learn why.

Comment: cross-posted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343044/install-r-in-linux-server

Answer (score 1):

This post

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149451/install-r-in-my-own-directory

says:

```
$ wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvf R-3.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.4.1
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/R
$ make && make install
```

Maybe you didn't do step 3, `cd`.

`configure` should run for several minutes, probing your system. It creates a lot of output. If `configure` stops with an error, I cannot help you further, unfortunately.

Comment: I have done all the steps that I realized I get an error about "zlib"

Comment: The error "zlib library and headers required"

Comment: I downloaded and configure zlib.1.2.11 but I still get same error

Comment: This zlib is a library for reading/writing compressed files (similar to zip files). R/configure wants the *source code* of this library in order to properly include it into R.  maybe you can pass the path of zlib to configure with `configure -- with-zlib=$HOME/zlib-1.2.11` (or similar) --- Can't you ask your system administrator to install R and its dependencies?